# Spark unable to mkdir when using groupie

Tags: python, docker, apache-spark, apache-kafka, group-by

I'm using spark in docker in order to do some processing. We got a Kafka container, Spark master container, two Spark workers containers and a Python container orchestrating the whole flow. We use `docker-compose` to bring everything up:

```
version: '3.4'

volumes:
  zookeeper-persistence:
  kafka-store:
  spark-store:

services:
  zookeeper-server:
    image: 'bitnami/zookeeper:3.6.1'
    expose:
      - '2181'
    environment:
     ...
    volumes:
      - zookeeper-persistence:/bitnami/zookeeper

  kafka-server:
    image: 'bitnami/kafka:2.6.0'
    expose:
      - '29092'
      - '9092'
    environment:
      ...
    volumes:
     - kafka-store:/bitnami/kafka
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper-server

  spark-master:
    image: bitnami/spark:3.0.1
    environment:
      SPARK_MODE: 'master'
      SPARK_MASTER_HOST: 'spark-master'
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
    expose:
      - '7077'
    depends_on:
      - kafka-server

  spark-worker1:
    image: bitnami/spark:3.0.1
    environment:
      SPARK_MODE: 'worker'
      SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY: '4G'
      SPARK_WORKER_CORES: '2'
    depends_on:
      - spark-master

  spark-worker2:
    #same as spark-worker1
  
  compute:
    build: ./app
    image: compute
    environment:
      KAFKA_HOST: kafka-server:29092
      COMPUTE_TOPIC: DataFrames
      PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS: "--master spark://spark-master:7077 --packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.0.0 pyspark-shell"
    depends_on:
      - spark-master
      - kafka-server
    volumes:
      - spark-store:/app/checkpoints
```

The data is send through another Python application and the compute container responds to changes. We create a ComputeDeployment and call the start function in order to start our Spark job:

```
def start(self):
        if self.compute_config.group_by:
            group_by_columns = ["value." + x for x in self.compute_config.group_by]
            agg_columns = [first(col("value." + x)).alias(x) for x in self.schema.names if x not in self.compute_config.group_by]
            select_columns = [x for x in self.schema.names]

            self.data_frame = self.data_frame \
                .select("key", "timestamp", from_json(col("value").cast("string"), self.schema).alias("value")) \
                .withWatermark("timestamp", "30 seconds") \
                .groupBy(*group_by_columns, window("timestamp", "30 seconds", "10 seconds")) \
                .agg(*agg_columns) \
                .select(struct(*select_columns).alias("value")) \
                .withColumn("value", col("value").cast(self.rename_schema)) \
                .select(col(f"value.{self.compute_config.identifier}").alias("key"), col("value").alias("value")) \
                .withColumn("key", col("key").cast("binary"))

        else:
            self.data_frame = self.data_frame \
                .select("key", from_json(col("value").cast("string"), self.schema).alias("value")) \
                .withColumn("value", col("value").cast(self.rename_schema))

        if self.build_columns:
            for column in self.build_columns:
                self.data_frame = self.data_frame.withColumn("value", struct("value.*", (function_mapping[column['build']['function']](*column['builder'])).alias(column['name'])))

        self.ds = self.data_frame.withColumn("value", to_json("value")) \
            .writeStream \
            .format("kafka") \
            .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", KAFKA_HOST) \
            .option("topic", self.compute_config.topic_target) \
            .option("checkpointLocation", f"/app/checkpoints/{self.compute_config.topic_target+str(self.compute_config.id)}") \
            .outputMode("update") \
            .start()
```

The else part of `if self.compute_config.group_by:` works without any problem. The groupie part however causes the following exception:

```
Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2059)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:2008)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:2007)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2007)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:973)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:973)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:973)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2239)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2188)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2177)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:775)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2099)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.V2TableWriteExec.writeWithV2(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:382)
    ... 37 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: mkdir of file:/app/checkpoints/driver10/state/0/0 failed
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.primitiveMkdir(FileSystem.java:1280)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.DelegateToFileSystem.mkdir(DelegateToFileSystem.java:183)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFs.mkdir(FilterFs.java:212)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext$4.next(FileContext.java:804)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext$4.next(FileContext.java:800)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSLinkResolver.resolve(FSLinkResolver.java:90)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.mkdir(FileContext.java:807)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.FileContextBasedCheckpointFileManager.mkdirs(CheckpointFileManager.scala:303)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.state.HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider.init(HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider.scala:224)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.state.StateStoreProvider$.createAndInit(StateStore.scala:230)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.state.StateStore$.$anonfun$get$1(StateStore.scala:366)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.getOrElseUpdate(HashMap.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.state.StateStore$.get(StateStore.scala:365)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.state.StateStoreRDD.compute(StateStoreRDD.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:349)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:313)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:349)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:313)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:349)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:313)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:349)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:313)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:446)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1377)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:449)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I don't get it why using the groupby causes an exception and the other part doesn't. It is driving me crazy because somehow it behaves differently without finding any documentation about differences.

Streaming to the console does work (because of not using checkpoints off course):

```
self.data_frame \
    .writeStream \
    .format("console") \
    .option("truncate", "false") \
    .start()
```

Produces this:

```
+-------------------------+--------------------------------------------+
|key                      |value                                       |
+-------------------------+--------------------------------------------+
|[00 00 00 00 07 59 C7 6E]|[name, 116, 123324270]                      |
|[00 00 00 00 0B 2E E6 68]|[name, 116, 187623016]                      |
...
```

As expected in our specific case.

Can someone help me out?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Check the permissions of /app/checkpoints

Comment: @OneCricketeer `/app/checkpoints` is a docker volume mapped to the compute container. Should I mount it to the spark containers too? And just make it accessible to all users?

Comment: It's the checkpoints, right? That will need mapped to every Spark worker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It had to do with permissions. Thanks to [OneCricketeer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2308683/onecricketeer) I've found out the user in the Spark container couldn't write to the directory. Fixed it with this entrypoint file:

```
#!/bin/bash

chmod -R a+rwX /app/checkpoints/

python -u run.py
```